# HTML, remove border from top-left cell of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a html table, my top-left cell is empty and I want to remove its border.

I tried with some css:

```
.border-less {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

That I applied to my top left cell:

```
<td class="border-less"></td>
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: And does the `tr` containing that `td` have a border?

Comment: probably your `table` has already a border. Try `table{border:0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/887/)**

```
table tr.border-less>td {
    border-top: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove border from `table` and `tr` and apply border only for `td`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
td.border-less {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-less"></td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this

**CSS**

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.border-less {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/jfvhxy59/